# Fix GridView at screen center

Tags: html, css, asp.net

There is **ALREADY CENTERD** Gridview. (by setting field: 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" )

How do I fix the position of a Gridview on the center of the screen.

When I add columns dynamically I do not want the whole GridView to move.

This is the original GridView:

- The red point is the center of the screen

[image]

- I want to maintain the red dot in the center of the screen after adding columns like the yellow ones below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i place Gridview center of div or panel.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084575/how-can-i-place-gridview-center-of-div-or-panel)

Comment: It's not the same question - because i'm not asking how to center GV. My question is - How GV will still on center after columns will be added dynamically  ?

Comment: @EliasMP, There is no much code to add for this question.. the only thing i coded for centerintg current gv is: HorizontalAlign="Center" ..

Comment: @NatanKara. It is hard for other users start from zero. Usually we start from a MCVE which provide a context about your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But There is No something to add! Except of the fact that initally the most right columns are not displayed, but after page load - when they are displayes - whole gv is mooving. and that what i want prevent !  Really not recognize what more i can add to clerify my question... !!

Comment: @NatanKara We are not mind readers, we cannot guess how your site is working! Thats why we need to see your code so we can understand what you have working and why you might be getting this issue. Without having something to go on, we cannot help.